# access time for card reader

Tags: flash, speed

What is the access time for reading flash via a built in card reader?

Would installing an OS or using a flash card for swap be faster than a hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is completely dependent on the interface ("built in" is not an interface), type of card, and the card's rated speed.

Comment: is there a way to test the speed?  I have a 16 gb 'netbook sdhc card', not sure what that means.

Comment: The "class" of a SD card will give you the rated speed in MBps, but you can use something like Bonnie++ to get a more accurate value.

Comment: sweet. thanks. ALSO: just found out, the 'disk utility' in gnome does benchmarking...